# How do you change the brightness values for the keyboard function keys?

Tags: laptop, brightness, backlight

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP Spectre x360 13". My brightness keys work great, however I'd like to be able to change the minimum brightness displayed. For instance, at the lowest possible setting before going black, I have this:

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
1201
```

However this is extremely bright in a dark room. A value of `200` would be more appropriate. Is there a way to adjust this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> A value of 200 would be more appropriate. Is there a way to adjust this?

```
echo 200 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

But I doubt if that is what you want. Try it and edit the question if this is not the expected result.